# Generating an executable using batch file... WAIT WHAT?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

So about a year ago i was working on a little project and i was looking for something to have some dynamic colors in batch (to change only a few words' color for example). I found this :

```
[CODE INTRO]
call :TXTCOLOR
set COLOR=TXTCOLOR.exe

[CODE]

:TXTCOLOR
    Echo.Const W=^2>t.vbs&Echo.Set o=WScript.StdOut>>t.vbs
    For %%b In (
    "4D53434600000000BA030000000000002C000000000000000301010001000000000000"
    "004900000001000100D20700000000000000009E3B8A662000747874636F6C6F722E65"
    "78650063EB078D6903D207434BDD544B681341189E6D538D35352AE2030F4EC44A458D"
    "55113C88D4C75A85AA5B5A2F8AD66D324997A6BB7177A2297868498B9450ECA182871E"
    "7AF0E0C183878AA98844DA83828288074FE24549B1A00785452AEB3F8F3C5A7C54BD39"
    "F0E77F7FF3CD9FD9397976045523847C209E87500E89D5847EBFFA40566C7AB0024D2C"
    "7B1ECA292DCF43ED5D868393B615B7F51E1CD14DD3A2B893603B6562C3C4474FB7E11E"
    "2B4AC27575B55B2486A622D4A254CDC37D8B82D5CB9525F3624DABE167250896EC985D"
    "25782354D6A851C4A70F237E2E5EB8B25297145F1701EFC022CEFAA76B0C70F7FF221F"
    "A6244D8B644036540BDE950B202E86A33AD5C17EA188C04BA6E78F864D23FFB73CCF0C"
    "BDEB9F6D006324ABFA33AE2F38180016593590C9FBB2FED6C228789969DF903AC7637E"
    "16EB2BC6DCAC3A9771157E6782A3F9C17C7060032A77071F295AE19C289EB9C413505E"
    "5559DEB4B07C872867B97D15B9CC6385A7EBCAE9B5909EA945F2CACE0498C586F3A146"
    "04D80FA7EDFE8CA25FEE995704C53298E865C7630D5F7983CBCC8F254E93EC8F6B9D64"
    "95AD6C28190E12280D6AB2767E3E52CC33D47ED7637CAE8D0BE48C8B8203AB8AB6121C"
    "A86124328CCE17CFF3B44258617C3E0FAB6FB4ACFA592B6C55F830FBDFB24F5684362A"
    "9259207BD21D525F0F3E9530FC544B71139A616EAE062CE8789D455A0E31BBC04E0BCC"
    "82F7D5F702EA45690EEB99E5E75553BCCAC747CCE7F374AA747FD6B0FB9313439BCDB1"
    "0F0FB091025D3778979F776985EB0263589DD578B5360CDB0DAB2EC89C56E8E5D9358C"
    "02CC010462E7BF791E9FDAA7ACFA492B5C1000B0B5573F86D9E5F1EAC7A5BE25F56DA9"
    "A7A57E22F533A9EF487D57EA09A973523FC48B79FBFE9755EFD43B08AE084DD38895B0"
    "EC304913DCA947BAE3B69532A30D8D3B8F6D8B5936A970E181374C7A8A5C69314CD2D0"
    "B86BF736BC997611CC5EB4CDB50BF05FE1B21D08897771AE22761562D3F8C7DCD6410E"
    "836C07D9077210A419A41D8480A442A26E08F44D907BA17FEBEB712E476C1A8E2612E0"
    "38D44E10130CC349478DB841B959B4204B2D56C6671103A3236299D4B612B124733A1C"
    "423BF464B283F626090FC409EDD10D53B7E30EF8240D30DDC4364962EF1EB96333A16D"
    "347A5C37A30922DC2396E95809D216B109310FA76231629F30631624DB4AC97698FA21"
    ) Do >>t.vbs (
    Echo.For b=1To 69Step 2:o.Write Chr(Clng("&H"^&Mid(%%b,b,W^)^)^):Next)
    For %%b In ("4A6DA33345591BFA0E"
    ) Do >>t.vbs (
    Echo.For b=1To 17Step 2:o.Write Chr(Clng("&H"^&Mid(%%b,b,W^)^)^):Next)
    Cscript /Nologo t.vbs > TXTCOLOR.ex_
    Del /f /q /a t.vbs >nul 2>&1
    Expand -r TXTCOLOR.ex_ >nul 2>&1
    Del /f /q /a TXTCOLOR.ex_ >nul 2>&1
    Goto :Eof
:----------------------------------------------

[END]
```

This generates a .exe that allows us to change the color within the batch file with the following syntax :

```
%COLOR% [COLOR CODE] [LINE PARAMETER] "[TEXT]"
```

[COLOR CODE] is the classic cmd color system with the first character being the background id and the second one being the text color id. [LINE PARAMETER] is 0 if it's not the last part of the line or 1 if it is. And of course, [TEXT] is the text.

For example, if i want to write "Hello world test" with "hello" and "test" in white and "world" in light green (everything with back baground), it should look like this:

```
%COLOR% 0F 0 "Hello "
%COLOR% 0A 0 "world "
%COLOR% 0F 1 "test"
```

I put 1 on the last one because it's the end of the line.

Finally, we come to my question : how does the thing work ? I mean, using a batch we're generating a .exe capable of being used as a command in the CMD. But how to generate one that is working ?

Thank you if you at least read until here, even if you don't have any answer.
Have a nice day ;)

Comment: well that big array is a hex dump of a .cab file

Comment: "But how to generate one that is working ?" - so you say the code that you posted does not work? I won't try that, but maybe you did. What exactly don't you understand in the given code?

Comment: Which part of the above code is unclear? Which parts are clear? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is `echo`ing a lot of stuff into (`>>`) the file `t.vbs`, i.e. it is creating a VBScript file.

The VBScript file is then executed (`Cscript /Nologo t.vbs`) and the output of the VBScript is written into `TXTCOLOR.ex_`.

Since `TXTCOLOR.ex_` is a compressed file, it is `Expand`ed, which will give you `TXTCOLOR.exe` which can be executed.

> But how to generate one that is working?

If you want to do the same for a different executable, just reverse the order of steps:

1. create an executable
2. compress it so that it has less bytes
3. get a hex dump of it
4. write a VBScript file which can convert the hex dump into a binary file
5. Write a batch file that writes a VBScript file

But: if you just want to execute some code, you can implement that in the executable right away. It's less error prone and less effort. Obfuscating stuff like that makes it suspicious.

Comment: Oh SHEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEH
Ok looks to complicated for me lol
Thanks for the answer, at least I learned something today lmao
Have a nice day sir !

Comment: Perhaps you may find [this thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6281) educative...